# Selecting specific user data with meteor-presence

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Is it possible to retrieve specific user data (e.g. `profile.name` or even something else within `profile` object) with [meteor-presence](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-presence) instead of returning userId? Or should I collect all userIds from `Meteor.presences` and then query `Meteor.users` with each `userId` to get the data I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is the best way to do it. You could use transform in your query too!

```
Meteor.presences.find({}, {transform:function(doc) {
        var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:doc.userId});
        if(user) doc.profile = user.profile;
        return doc;
    }
});
```

You can use this query in your template helper or pretty much anywhere else so that it now has a `profile` object to match the user. Make sure though all your users in your user collection are published in a safe way.

Comment: Thanks for helping Akshat! However, I'm a bit confused with this code snippet... I tried to play with it on server and client side but I don't get anything in return. I tried `console.log(doc)` and `console.log(user)` within the function, but nothing -.- Should I pass something to this `transform` option at all? What is this `doc` in that function? Sorry but I'm really a beginner with mongodb =/

Comment: The transform function takes the document it would return and changes it to whatever is in the transform function. Its odd it didn't return anything via `console.log`. Is your `Meteor.presences` collection & `Meteor.users` collection published? If you checked the output by adding `.fetch()` (to make it `.find({},{..}).fetch()` does it show the profile field by running it in your webkit console?

Comment: Hmhm, well, seems like it works if I use `.fetch()` in the end. If I omit that part and try to `console.log()` my result I get `undefined`, but with `fetch()` I get proper objects in return. Do you want to update your answer so I can accept it? You're also missing one curly bracket after `return doc;` line :) Thanks for helping and explanations!!!

Comment: Oh i see! The reason for this is you have to actually use it (without the fetch) for it to get the results as opposed to just letting the above snippet run on its own (i.e use it in your template html or use `.forEach` to get the data out). Meteor uses a sort of 'lazy cursor' optimization by not calling the records until you actually use them (`fetch` forces it to get them) but it should work fine in your code without it.

Comment: Where would you store the above code? Client side or server side?

Comment: AH thanks, I have been playing around Ims till struggling how to output one of the attributes from the user object like userName, any ideas?

Comment: Any help of how you showed the info in the templates would be awesome, Im really stuck and a proper noob with meteor.